# Unable to deploy Hello_Endpoints project in Google App Engine server. Launcher is not asking username and password?

Tags: google-app-engine

When i try to deploy the below error is thrown by the Launcher.

> 2017-04-12 05:02:10 Running command: "['C:\Python27\pythonw.exe',
>   '-u', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py',
>   '--oauth2_credential_file=C:\Users\Rajath/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens',
>   'update', 'H:\GOOGLE
>   AppEngine\Git\ud858\Lesson_2\000_Hello_Endpoints']" 05:02 AM
>   Application: thermal-petal-164215; version: 1 05:02 AM Host:
>   appengine.google.com Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 133,
>   in 
>       run_file(**file**, globals())   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 129, in run_file
>       execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line
>   5521, in 
>       main(sys.argv)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line
>   5512, in main
>       result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line
>   2975, in Run
>       self.action(self)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line
>   5168, in **call**
>       return method()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line
>   3900, in Update
>       self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line
>   3921, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
>       updatecheck.CheckForUpdates()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\sdk_update_checker.py",
>   line 245, in CheckForUpdates
>       runtime=runtime))   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc_httplib2.py",
>   line 246, in Send
>       url, method=method, body=payload, headers=headers)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2__init__.py", line
>   1607, in request
>       (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)   File
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2__init__.py", line
>   1355, in _request
>       (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2__init__.py", line
>   1291, in _conn_request
>       conn.connect()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2__init__.py", line
>   1060, in connect
>       raise SSLHandshakeError(e) httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>   2017-04-12 05:02:24 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.

Comment: And it runs successfully in local server.